# How To 'Read From .csv and Write To excel' In The Same Loop

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript

I'm attempting to read from a .csv file and paste that data onto a 3270 terminal screen while writing the result of those attempts to a corresponding excel file that mirrors the .csv exactly

I've created the code that reads from the .csv file and pastes the value onto the 3270 screen.  But having difficultly referencing the exact line/row in excel to write the result

Here is my Loop:

```
  strLine = objFile.ReadLine
  Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream                
     arrFields = Split(strLine,",") 
     subDoWork (strLine)
  strLine = strLine + 1
  Loop
```

subDoWork then reads the .csv and pastes the data:

```
Sub subDoWork(strLine)

    ColumnA = arrFields(0)
    ColumnB = arrFields(1)

     subMoveCursor 1, 10                                                                                             
     subEnterData ColumnA

    If (funcReadScreen(12,27,1) <> "0") Then

      oExcelObject.Cells(3).Value = "Skipped SAF1"
      oExcelObject.DisplayAlerts = False
      ExcelWorkbook.Save
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm creating the objects here and setting the variables when getting the extenal file:

```
Set oExcelObject = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oFileObject  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

 Sub subExternalFile
   rw = 2
   strFilter = ""
   strExternalFilePath = funcSolicitFile(strFilter)
   strExternalFilePath1 = 
     "\\DAYFS02\mortvc$\_Scripts_Custom\DisasterScript_OutPut.xlsx"
       Set objFile  = oFileObject.OpenTextFile(strExternalFilePath)
       Set oExcelFile   = oFileObject.GetFile(strExternalFilePath1)
       strExcelFileName = oExcelFile.Name
       Set oExcelObject = GetObject("","Excel.Application")
       Set ExcelWorkbook = 
       oExcelObject.Workbooks.Open(strExternalFilePath1)
       Set oExcelSheet   = ExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1)
   oExcelObject.Application.Visible = False
 End Sub
```

I'm expecting to read from line 1 of the text file.  To read arrfields(0) and arrfields(1), only two columns, then paste that data onto the 3270 screen. And if the screen reads something specifically, to write to line 1 of the excel file in column C (3).  Then move to Line 2 and do the same, read the .csv file and then write to column (3) of the corresponding line number in the excel file.

When it tries to write to the excel file, I get the error that the object can't be found.  Although I am creating the object.  I also get a "Type mismatch" error when trying to count strLine so that I can move to the next line/row.

--------Edit 05/29/2019----------
I got that working.  I'm able to move from line to line within the .csv file and paste to the screen.  However, when writing to excel, it overwrites column C (row 2, the first row is headers) every time.  I can't get it to write into row 3 column C of excel based off the result in line 3 of the .csv.  I'm also not identifying the first line of the .csv as headers, in fact I removed the header from the .csv, but still have the header in the excel file (row 1). So technically, line 1 in the .csv is row 2 in excel.  I'm not sure if I need to place a Loop within my first Loop in order to count the rows in excel and ensure I'm writing to the correct row in excel based of the line in the .csv.  your assistance is appreciated.

Comment: So it turns out, that I am able to write to the excel file with the above code.  But I am unable to make it to the next line in the text file (.csv) and then subsequently, to that corresponding line in the excel file.  I am unable to count the lines in the text file like rows in excel strLine actually gives me the text from the line instead of an integer to count, so that I can make it to the next line in the .csv and the corresponding row in the excel output file

Comment: so I need help moving from line 1 to line 2 and so on, in the text file.  As well as writing to column C in the excel file for lines 1 and 2 and so on.

Comment: don't add extra information in comments please. Just edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a type mismatch because you are trying to add an integer (1) to a string in this line.

```
strLine = strLine + 1
```

If you want to keep track of which line you are working on you need to dim a new line counter variable.
You also need to read the line inside of the loop, or you'll end up with an endless loop.

Something like this:

```
dim i
i = 0
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream   
   strLine = objFile.ReadLine             
   arrFields = Split(strLine,",") 
   subDoWork  strLine
   i = i + 1
Loop
```